# Is use of `auto` for a function argument against the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, c++14

Does code like this:

```
auto add(auto a, auto b) { return a + b; }
```

violate the ISO c++14 standard? Will future versions of the standard allow code to be written like that?

Comment: This is part of the Concepts TS, not C++14. I cannot find a dupe for some reason...

Comment: Yes; I fixed it

Comment: Logics tells that the compiler has no hint to infer a type and this cannot work. (And as the function is not templated, there is no reason to create overloads on demand.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust That makes no sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [Does this] violate the ISO c++14 standard?

Yes, you can not declare functions taking parameters using `auto` in C++14 (or C++17 for that matter). This code is ill-formed.

> Will future versions of the standard allow code to be written like that?

The current Concepts TS does allow for this, it's usually referred to as terse function template syntax. In Concepts, the meaning is equivalent to:

```
template <class T, class U>
auto add(T a, U b) { return a + b; }
```

That part of the Concepts proposal also allows concept names to be used, not just `auto`. It is an open question as to whether this will be part of a future C++ standard.

---

Update: The code will be valid in C++20, and have meaning equivalent to the function template I showed above (NB: `a` and `b` are deduced independently).

Answer (score 3):

If you want that to mean that you can pass any type to the function, make it a template:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> int add(T1 a, T2 b);
```

Alternatively, you could use a lambda:

```
auto add = [](const auto& a, auto& b){ return a + b; };
```

is [Proposal for Generic (Polymorphic) Lambda Expressions](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3559.pdf). *However, generic lambdas are a C++14 feature.*

Comment: OP is talking about functions, not lambdas... -1.

Comment: lamdas can be thought as definition of a function declaration, lambda is a function but indirectly

Comment: `a` and `b` must have the same type in your first example, and is not equivalent in any sense to your lambda, or what OP seems to be asking for.

Comment: @snr I'm sure it was [when I wrote that](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44979612/2)

Comment: Why is your function returning an `int`? That is definitely not equivalent to the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment this is invalid but maybe in a future version of the standard it will be the equivalent of:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto add(T1 a, T2 b) {return a + b;}
```

Answer (score -1):

For C++ 20 and above, this is valid and will behave as you might expect.

There is a workaround for compilers which dont support C++ 20, using function macros and templates:

```
#define add(a,b) add_real_function<decltype(a),decltype(b)>(a,b)

template <typename T1,typename T2>
auto add_real_function(T1 a, T2 b) { return a + b; }
```

Keep in mind that the real name of your function (`add_real_function` here) must differ from the name you want to give to your function(`add` here), which must be the name of the macro.

Unfortunately, this workaround comes with the drawback that you cannot create function pointers to these kind of functions.

Comment: OP's code is valid in C++20. Your code is unnecessarily complicated, you can replace `auto` in parameters with `T1`,`T2`, then the macro can be removed. Moreover, your version also requires C++20, since it uses the same feature as the OP's code.

Comment: Regarding the edit: now, the macro is outright unnecessary, since the compiler can deduce template arguments for `add_real_function`.